# When should I choose lower-size bytes variables (e.g. bytes23) over bytes32 variables?

Tags: memory, bytes, bytes32, state-variable

I am trying to manage strings on a smart contract. I know these strings will be 46 bytes long so I thought I could convert them into bytes and split them in two bytes32 arrays. Then I realized smaller bytes sizes exist, so I opted for two bytes23 arrays. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by “manage strings.”

Ideally you’d just keep things simple and use `string`, but yes, if you’re going to be storing these strings on-chain, then it would be a huge waste to store as `string` because for each 46-byte string you’d use 2 storage slots for the 46 bytes, and an extra storage slot to write the length `46` every time.

It really depends on what you plan to do with these strings. For example, if you’re going to store an array of these 46-byte strings, it would save you a lot of storage gas to pack them all after each other back to back. In this way e.g. 10 46-byte strings would occupy 10 × 46 bytes = 460 bytes ≈ 15 slots, rather than 10 × 64 bytes = 640 bytes = 20 slots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically, those strings are IPFS CIDs and they will be stored in an array of CID, a struct I created composed of two bytes23 object. My dapp flow is structured in rounds and each of these rounds will have its own array of CIDs. So if i am getting it right, as long as i store them one after the other it makes sense using smaller structure (bytes23 in this case), am i right? –

Comment: I read [here](https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/content-addressing/#version-0-v0) that if a CID is 46 characters starting with "Qm", it's a base58-encoded CIDv0 which [when converted to binary](https://github.com/multiformats/cid/blob/ef1b2002394b15b1e6c26c30545fd485f2c4c138/README.md#decoding-algorithm) is simply a 34-byte chunk of data that always starts `0x1220…`, which means that you can store it in a single `bytes32` and avoid a lot of trouble. Just make sure you know what type of CID you are dealing with before you proceed further.

Comment: To give a more general answer… as on-chain storage is expensive, you always want to be storing data using as little bytes as possible. So you should always deal with base256-encoded data (binary) rather than data that has been encoded with less symbols (e.g. base58) to be more human-friendly. Other than that, I suggest you [search this forum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=cid+solidity) as some related questions have already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to stay with the usual types until you have the requirement to optimize the contract.

Trying to optimize a contract without an specific purpose will only make it more difficult to read and make changes.